# Is it necessary to pay attention to non-error prompts? like no package ‘***’ found？

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

These prompts exist during the compilation of OPENCV, but no error is reported after the compilation. Generally, if there is no error prompt, I will not pay attention to the information, but I am also worried about it. So, I want to know whether it is necessary to solve these non-error prompts? Thank you.

```
Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.22.30
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.56.4
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   Found libdc1394-2, version 2.2.5
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
*****
*****
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for dgemm_
-- Looking for dgemm_ - found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
********
********
- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.
**********
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/timothy/Documents/opencv-3.4.1/build
```

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/is-it-necessary-to-pay-attention-to-non-error-prompts-like-no-package-found/10370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not familiar with how `Configure` style scripts work, you're probably quite overwhelmed by what's going on here.

These sorts of scripts look for a lot of different dependencies, some optional, some mandatory, and there might be more than one option for each dependency.

If something is missing that may or may not be a problem, you need to observe the output carefully and see if it reached the "Done" state, or if it halted early because of a missing dependency.

In many cases if it succeeds, you're fine, but a missing dependency may translate to missing features. For example, a missing `libpng` might mean no PNG support. You'll have to consult the documentation for the implications.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need features that depends on the missing packages, it's OK. Mostly a well maintained library will work fine at runtime for all features configured at compile time.

Even if you don't know what specific features are required, you don't need to worry. Because you will find out what's required when you build, test or optimize your program.

The VTK related error in the log means the VTK package in your system was broken. If you need a VTK feature, I recommend to install a more recent VTK version.